# Is it possible to show a part of a web in a webview?

Tags: android, html, webview

I want to know if there is a way to show a part of a web in a webview.

I want to show only a specific DIV of an URL, from the next part of HTML I want to get only the info inside DIV "magazine-news". Is it possible?

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="header-v4">
        <div class="container content">
          <div class="row category margin-bottom-20">
             <div> </div>
             <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                <div class="container">
                   <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-9">
                         <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:#438e2a; color:#FFF; padding:20px; font-size:24px; margin-bottom:30px; text-align:center; margin-top:20px">
                            <div class="headline headline-md">
                               <div class="magazine-news">
```

I post a screenshot, to see it better.

[image]

Comment: please can you add actual code that closed this is stressing me out

Comment: Is a external web, not mine. It's possible to get this data knowing only the structure?

Comment: you need to get specific div using the javaparser library , wrap to html tags and manually add css

Comment: I think it is possible but what you would have to do is create a php or preprocessor page which loads in the wanted content which you then webview which might be the only option unless you can execute javascript to the webview

Comment: can you execute javascript to the webview?

Answer (score 0):

use a HTML parser library like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) then get the body element html string and load it on the webview